# How to do a scrollViewer in TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

I'm editing the ControlTemplate for a window with a TabControl.
The ItemsSource is a list of TabItem with Headers and Contents.

Here is my code :

```
<TabControl Margin="8,0,8,10" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Licenses}" Template="{DynamicResource TabControlControlTemplate}"/>
    <!--<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>-->
</TabControl>
```

I want to add a scrollviewer around the TextBlock.

Licenses,Header,Content are dependencyProperty, so only TemplateBinding is allowed.

H and V ScrollBar visibility in TextBlock line freeze the window, so I can't use it.

How I can do this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're templating the `Header` which is usually small (like a button), what's the purpose of fitting a ScrollViewer to such a small space? I think you may want to the re-template the `Content` of `TabItem` instead.

Comment: Thanks you, it was a small mistake because I paste it from a project with style not like mine.